# What is the relation between length of data block and file length in varint?

Tags: protocol-buffers

In proto stream when decoding the file size and data block length in varint, the data block length is bigger than the file size? Please Help

Comment: What is `varint`?

Comment: Please choose only one tag: [tag:c] or [tag:c++]. If the code should be complatible with C, use only [tag:c] tag.

Comment: Are "proto stream"s related to [tag:protocol-buffers]? Neither "proto stream"s or "varint" are things in either plain C or plain C++, so people who can answer this question are more likely to find it if you use the appropriate tags.

Comment: I think he may be talking about Google protobuf messaging, but this question deserves to be terminated

Comment: @VadimKotov There are plenty of questions that should be tagged both, just like there are questions that should be tagged both [tag:C] and [tag:Python]. I do agree that most questions that get tagged both should only be one or the other (usually [tag:C++]), and I'm not sure this one should actually have *either* tag.

Comment: @DanielH I agree. Also refer to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281213/1000551

Answer (score 1):

> the data block length is bigger than the file size

That sounds unlikely, and is most likely the result of (any one of):

- a broken encoder (very unlikely if you're using any of the established implementations, but not impossible)
- corruption of the data-stream in transit (the most common variant of this being: using a text-encoding such as UTF-8 ***backwards*** to try to get a string - when *if* a string is really needed, something like base-16 (hex) or base-64 should be used)
- accidentally truncating a stream prematurely
- a broken decoder

It sounds like you're parsing the stream manually, so frankly my guess is the last option. If you can post the bytes you're decoding we can probably advise on whether your interpretation is correct. Alternatively, you can try pushing your data through https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode which will pull apart the data-stream and show how it has interpreted the bytes.

Comment: Please review the below

Comment: @BradMcquaid 00 is invalid as a first byte in protobuf; the data makes no sense. How did you get this output?

Comment: Please have a look at the file below.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8zoMrtMjVGdbkxrVFRHSE1fUUEtTGJxdzEyVmQybWhTbVlj

Comment: @BradMcquaid isn't IWA wrapped in "snappy"?

Answer (score 0):

00 E4 02 00 A5 0A F0 3E 1E 08 C9 3F 12 19 08 05 12 03 01 00 05 18 75 2A 0E AE 44 93 42 AF 44 BF 3F B2 44 B1 44 B0 44 0A 03 08 93 42 22 33 12 31 42 2F 0A 0A 54 72 61 6E 73 69 74 69 6F 6E 12 04 6E 6F 6E 65 19 00 00 01 02 08 F0 3F 29 01 07 01 01 54 30 00 58 EB D4 FF AA 07 80 01 00 2A 03 08 AF 44 32 03 08 AE 44 3A 0D 05 78 AF 44 8A 01 03 08 BF 3F 98 01 01 A2 01 03 08 B0 44 DA 01 03 08 B2 44 A2 02 03 08 B1 44 D2 02 01 26 01 06 28 AF 44 1F 08 AE 44 12 1A 08 07 12 05 94 A0 C3 01 22 08 0A 04 0A 02 01 06 18 01 2A 04 B3 44 DC 3B 0A BE 01 0A AF 01 0A 3E 0A 1F 0A 0A 0D 00 00 C8 42 15 00 00 5A 43 12 01 0C E0 4E 44 15 00 00 E1 43 18 03 25 00 00 00 00 12 03 08 C9 3F 1A 12 08 04 10 02 18 01 25 00 00 40 41 2D 00 00 00 3F 30 00 28 00 38 00 12 03 08 DC 3B 1A 68 08 00 10 00 2A 62 12 1D 3D 18 1A 54 0A 0E 08 01 12 01 12 08 00 00 15 01 48 0C 0A 0E 08 02 05 10 05 5F 00 00 3A 10 00 04 E1 43 15 20 05 30 14 E1 43 0A 02 08 05 3E 44 00 14 12 03 08 B3 44 22 01 05 30 30 01 10 03 15 08 B3 44 12 10 08 D1 0F 09 E4 F0 4A 6C 2A 04 83 42 C7 41 12 03 08 A8 3F 1A 1F 41 66 74 65 72 20 4B 65 79 6E 6F 74 65 20 38 3F 29 0A 62 75 6C 6C 65 74 20 77 6F 6D 62 61 74 2A 0D 0A 07 08 00 12 03 08 83 42 0A 02 08 12 32 08 0A 06 08 00 10 00 18 00 3A 09 0A 07 08 01 69 10 C7 41 50 01 72 15 17 04 9A 01 05 0B 10 12 02 65 6E C2 09 0B 18 10 00 18 00 1F 08 AF 62 65 01 0C C0 41 B5 44 4E 65 01 04 A0 41 39 06 00 40 9E 65 01 08 C0 41 1A 42 65 01 00 40 C2 65 01 00 40 3A 65 01 00 40 5E 65 01 00 B5 21 65 00 B5 21 65 0C 02 15 08 B5 2E 65 01 18 4F 2A 04 AE 3B A2 40 29 65 08 06 57 6F 25 4C 31 33 08 A2 40 32 25 26 21 1B 00 3A 11 15 04 AE 3B 86 48 01 18 12 08 B2 44 12 0D 08 2D C9 0C 05 2A 02 B4 61 35 10 B4 44 15 08 B4 2E 7D 00 00 3E 01 7D 0C AC 3B 08 04 05 7F 15 77 04 AC 3B 82 77 00 3D B4 20 0F 08 B1 44 12 0A 08 E7 17 49 36 0C 00 1F 08 B0 62 C4 01 08 DB 40 B6 3E C4 01 18 00 44 15 00 80 3D 44 25 C4 20 48 42 15 00 00 E8 41 18 00 92 29 03 04 DB 40 32 C4 01 0D 3D 6A 29 03 05 22 7D 29 05 10 04 E8 41 36 29 03 04 E8 41 5A 29 03 00 B6 21 C4 00 B6 21 C4 18 01 17 08 B6 44 12 12 75 29 20 4C 2A 06 AE 3B C0 40 B7 44 25 47 10 1A 03 EF BF BC 35 4C 00 C0 56 C3 01 00 4A 31 CE 04 B7 44 2E CE 01 32 57 01 00 B7 21 57 00 FB 2D C4 44 11 0A 04 0A 00 10 00 10 00 22 07 64 65 63 69 6D 61 6C

Decoding the first six bytes

Comment: 00 is invalid as a first byte in protobuf; the data makes no sense. How did you get this output?